# Is it possible to input data into JSON file with url?

Tags: android, json

Is it possible to input data into JSON file with URL? I know there are tons of tutorials how you can show JSON data from URL, but not how to input data into that JSON file.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to create entity (object) and parse your json file (with gson for example). Update your object and generate new json file with the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Json files are usually generated by  database queries.

you can create your own json file using one of the many android json tools, 
and then upload it via a programatically-coded FTP client connected to the hosting server, but a json file is a text file, and you must download -> parse data -> add new data -> transform data into json file again -> upload process, as far as i know.

Answer (score 0):

Even i tried to do this while i was thinking about making an app offline. Later i preferred a better way, create local sqlite database.